# I can't understand the scope of named controller in Angularjs and the use of keyword this

Tags: javascript, angularjs, this

I'm trying to understand the use of named controllers (*controller as* syntax) in Angular.
In my app I have the same controller associated with some different divs. In html page the controllers is always named (`myCtrl as C`). And inside the controller I used `this`.  
The controller has some variables and some methods bound/called within html page.

I have some strange behavior that I tried to replicate in this example:

```
var app=angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function(){
    vm=this
    vm.name="Pippo";
    vm.msg=function(){alert(vm.name)}
})

app.controller("ctrl2", function(){
    this.name="Pippo";
    this.msg=function(){alert(this.name)}
})

app.controller("ctrl3", function($scope){
    $scope.name="Pippo";
    $scope.msg=function(){alert($scope.name)}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k66Za/111/

My case is the first one, the one using `ctrl1`. As you can see, what I expect clicking the first button is not what I get: instead of returning ctrl1 name it returns ctrl2 name.

Of course it's my lack, but I don't see the difference between ctrl1 and ctrl2. 
Could some one please explain to me what's happening in my example and if I should use `$scope`, `this` and, most of all, why using vm (where `vm=this`) is different from using `this`?

Comment: what is diff in between ctrl1 and ctrl2 name? isnt it same "Pippo"

Comment: `vm = this` is no different than just using `this` (at least in an Angular controller). You're just storing a reference to `this` in the `vm` variable, they both refer to the same function. I'm not seeing the behavior you describe, ctrl & ctrl2 both return what I would expect - different values

Comment: There are a lot of good resources out of there about this topic. I personally suggest to read http://toddmotto.com/rethinking-angular-js-controllers/ and http://toddmotto.com/opinionated-angular-js-styleguide-for-teams/, but there are a lof of others nice articles / guides, it's only matter to do a search on a search engine

Comment: Sorry, I didn't told you to change the content of input box. try this: http://jsfiddle.net/k66Za/112

Answer (score 1):

Technically there is no difference between ctrl and ctrl2.  The reason why you should do what you did in ctrl and not what you did in ctrl2 is this:

It is a good idea to bind the controller `this` to a variable so that you can reference it later.  `this` changes meaning depending on the context you use it in.  If you reference `this` inside a function, it refers to that function.  If you want to bind something to the controller from within a function, you cannot do it using `this`.

When we inject $scope into a controller, we use $scope as 'glue' between the controller and the view.  A sort of mediator between the two.  If we use `controller as` syntax we are dealing directly with the controller instance, and thus we must reference myCtrl.myVar instead of myVar (when it is attached to $scope).

You have this code in your fiddle:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl2 as c"  ng-init="c.name=3">
        Name: <input type="text" ng-model="c.name" />
        <input type="button" ng-click="c.msg()" value="I should show {{c.name}}" ></input>
        </div>

        <div ng-controller="ctrl2 as c"  ng-init="c.name=4">
        Name: <input type="text" ng-model="c.name" />
        <input type="button" ng-click="c.msg()" value="I should show {{c.name}}" ></input>
        </div>
```

It may seem that this code is behaving strangely, but it actually isn't.  Regardless of which button you click, they both give you back `4`.  This is because you are instantiating the same controller two times.  When angular digests the page it hits the first instantiation, assigns `3` to `c.name`, then it hits the second instantiation, which assigns `4` to `c.name`, so when you try to call up a reference to `c.name` it is giving you the second value.

Comment: I too thought ctrl1 and ctr2 are the same. But try to change the input boxes values: http://jsfiddle.net/k66Za/112. They are not the same thing.

Comment: It's because you are instantiating the same controller two times.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe I found a solution for my problem.
Take this example: http://jsfiddle.net/k66Za/113/ 
It doesn't work: clicking on the first button I get the value 2 (insted of 1)

Now I change the line `vm=this` in `var vm=this`

Everything now work as it should. Why? What's the difference?